# Remove all dom elements with specific tag?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I try to remove all head:book elements from following request excerpt:

```
<head:bookstore>
<head:book>9</head:book>
<head:book>10</head:book>
</head:bookstore>


requestHolder.getDomNodes("//head:bookstore/head:book").each {
    requestNode.removeChild(it)
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

updatE:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def requestHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("openBook#Request")
```

Comment: What is that `requestHolder`? This is not XMLSlurper, right? What's that object's class?

Comment: No it's GroovyUtils, updated above

Comment: How about requestNode? Which node is it holding at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below the solution to remove the nodes of the XML, please notice that you can get the entire xml and you may need to edit the nodes name of the below script

```
  // Get the entire request 
  def request = context.expand( '${Test Request#Request#declare namespace   soap=\'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\'; //soap:Envelope[1]}' )

// or create the XML 
def BOOKS = '''
<bookstore>
<book>9</book>
<book>10</book>
</bookstore>
 '''

def booksParser = new XmlParser().parseText(BOOKS)
def allBooks = booksParser.children()
booksParser.remove(allBooks)
new XmlNodePrinter().print(booksParser)
log.info booksParser
```